# pandas slicing nested values along with other columns

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I am trying to get the nested values from this below json data.

```
{
    "region_id": 60763,
    "phone": "",
    "address": {
        "region": "NY",
        "street-address": "147 West 43rd Street",
        "postal-code": "10036",
        "locality": "New York City"
    },
    "id": 113317,
    "name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square"
}
{
    "region_id": 32655,
    "phone": "",
    "address": {
        "region": "CA",
        "street-address": "300 S Doheny Dr",
        "postal-code": "90048",
        "locality": "Los Angeles"
    },
    "id": 76049,
    "name": "Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills"
}
```

I just loaded the above data in to my pandas data frame using:

```
with open("file path") as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line) for line in f)
```

Now my data frame looks like this:

```
   address                                              Phone
0  {u'region': u'NY', u'street-address': u'147 We...      
1  {u'region': u'CA', u'street-address': u'300 S ...   

       id                                             name  region_id
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square  60763   
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills  32655
```

I could get the column subset using this - `data = df[['id', 'name']]`

But not sure how I can get the values of `region` and `street-address` along with `id` and `name`. My output data frame should have `id, name, region, street-address`.

Note : I tried to pop out and concatenate this nested column `address` with my data frame. But since my data is huge - 348MB, concatenate takes huge memory when I try column-wise - (axis - 1).

Also I am looking for an efficient way to handle this, should I go with Numpy which will directly use the C extension. Or writing in to some database like MongoDB. I am considering this because after subsetting this data, I need to join this other dataset based on the id column to get few other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Pandas solution - [pandas.io.json.json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

Corrected and **working** version:

```
import ujson
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

with open('aaa') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)

df = json_normalize(data)[['id', 'name', 'address.region', 'address.street-address']].rename(columns={'address.region': 'region', 'address.street-address': 'street-address'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       id                                             name region        street-address
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square     NY  147 West 43rd Street
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills     CA       300 S Doheny Dr
```

NOT WORKING version (as Cleb has pointed out):

```
import ujson
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)

df = json_normalize(data, 'address', ['region', 'street-address'])

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
print(df)
```

Alternatively, you can use `ujson` (Ultra fast JSON) in order to generate list of dictionaries and then generate a DataFrame out of it:

```
import ujson
import pandas as pd

data_list = []

with open('data.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = ujson.loads(line)
        data_list.append(
            {"id":d["id"],
             "name":d["name"],
             "region":d["address"]["region"],
             "street-address":d["address"]["street-address"]
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
print(df)
```

I don't know which solution will be more efficient/faster - please give it a try against your real data (348MiB) and give us a short feedback.

PS if it's possible, call pd.DataFrame/pd.read_json only once, otherwise it will be much slower.

Output:

```
       id                                             name region        street-address
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square     NY  147 West 43rd Street
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills     CA       300 S Doheny Dr
```

Comment: Your first approach looks great! However, I get `KeyError: 'region'`. What could be the reason?

Comment: I updated my answer using your approach but slightly modified as your script does not run through on my computer. I upvote your answer as I really like this approach and did not hear about `json_normalize` before.

Comment: @Cleb, you are right. Thank you for pointing that out! I've tested another (old) script, instead of this one. I will fix it and will update my answer.

Comment: @Cleb Thanks to both of you. I tried both the options. Not sure why, but I keep getting key error when I try to normalise after the code runs for 125 secs or so. However, ujson is awesome. It runs the whole file in just 10sec and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeeva: Glad it worked. However, it is strange that you still receive the key error; it should neither occur in MaxU's corrected nor in my version below (have you tried that one)?

Answer (score 3):

The following would work (however, I added a more efficient solution below; just scroll down to the **EDIT**):

```
import pandas as pd

# read the updated json file
df = pd.read_json('data.json')

# convert column with the nested json structure
tempdf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index').T for item in df.address])

# get rid of the converted column
df.drop('address', 1, inplace=True)

# prepare concat
tempdf.index = df.index

# merge the two dataframes back together
df = pd.concat([df, tempdf], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       id                                             name phone  region_id  \
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square            60763   
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills            32655   

  region        street-address postal-code       locality  
0     NY  147 West 43rd Street       10036  New York City  
1     CA       300 S Doheny Dr       90048    Los Angeles
```

Now you can get rid of unwanted columns using the `drop` command.

I modified your json file which was actually not valid; you can check it e.g. on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/):

```
[{
    "region_id": 60763,
    "phone": "",
    "address": {
        "region": "NY",
        "street-address": "147 West 43rd Street",
        "postal-code": "10036",
        "locality": "New York City"
    },
    "id": 113317,
    "name": "Casablanca Hotel Times Square"
}, {
    "region_id": 32655,
    "phone": "",
    "address": {
        "region": "CA",
        "street-address": "300 S Doheny Dr",
        "postal-code": "90048",
        "locality": "Los Angeles"
    },
    "id": 76049,
    "name": "Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills"
}]
```

**EDIT**

Building up on @MaxU's answer (which did not work for me), you could also do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import ujson
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# this is the json file from above
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = ujson.load(f)
```

Now, as proposed by @MaxU, you can use [json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to get rid of the nested structure:

```
df3 = json_normalize(data)
```

This gives you:

```
  address.locality address.postal-code address.region address.street-address      id                                             name phone  region_id
0    New York City               10036             NY   147 West 43rd Street  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square            60763
1      Los Angeles               90048             CA        300 S Doheny Dr   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills            32655
```

You can rename the columns you want to keep like this:

```
df3.rename(columns={'address.region': 'region', 'address.street-address': 'street-address'}, inplace=True)
```

and then choose the columns you would like to keep:

```
df3 = df3[['id', 'name', 'region', 'street-address']]
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
       id                                             name region        street-address
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square     NY  147 West 43rd Street
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills     CA       300 S Doheny Dr
```

Answer (score 2):

A small helper function would do the trick:

```
def get_entries(line):
    data = json.loads(line)
    res = {k: data[k] for k in ['id', 'name']}
    res.update({k: data['address'][k] for k in ['region', 'street-address']})
    return res

with open("file path") as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(get_entries(line) for line in f)
```

Output:

```
       id                                             name region  \
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square     NY   
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills     CA   

         street-address  
0  147 West 43rd Street  
1       300 S Doheny Dr
```

Or, a bit nicer looking:

[image]

Comment: You had the same idea, but you were faster. I have up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a new dataframe with the `id` and `name` columns of `df`.  Then loop through each of your target fields (all located in `address`) and apply a `lambda` function to get the item from the dictionary.

```
df2 = df[['id', 'name']]
for col in ['region', 'street-address']:
    df2[col] = df.address.apply(lambda j: j.get(col))

>>> df2
       id                                             name region        street-address
0  113317                    Casablanca Hotel Times Square     NY  147 West 43rd Street
1   76049  Four Seasons Hotel Los Angeles at Beverly Hills     CA       300 S Doheny Dr
```